# Web Development Project - Front end vs backend (routing and file serving)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

I'm working on a personal project to create a recipe-based web application for streamlining our family's meat processing activities. I want to move away from manual paper-based processes and add this project to my development portfolio.

Currently, I'm using the MERN stack (MySQL, Express, React, and Node.js) along with Sequelize as the ORM. However, in my front-end bootcamp, we're focusing on React.js and Next.js.

Next.js provides automatic routing and the ability to build a full stack application within a single framework. My professor suggested using only Next.js and React.js, but I'm unsure about integrating the Node.js backend with Express and Sequelize. Should I let the backend handle file serving or should the front-end handle routing using Next.js, with Node.js only for the API and data management?

My Node.js backend is almost complete, except for specific association relationships and API calls that I haven't finalized yet.

I want to utilize Next.js for the frontend but not as the backend. I'd like to showcase my ability with Node.js as well.

I would appreciate your guidance on how to structure and set up this project efficiently, so that I can use it as a portfolio piece and increase my chances of securing a job as a full-stack/backend JavaScript developer.